# "CACLS" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch, cacls

I have been using CACLS batch file many times and today it is not recognized. `CACLS.EXE` exist in `C:\Windows\System32` and I have tried writing at command prompt:

```
CACLS * /E /T /C /G Administrators:F  
CACLS C:\Temp\[filename] /E /T /C /G Administrators:F
```

I am signed in as an Administrator and am using Windows XP Pro.

Please help. I can change the ownership and permission individually but this is tedious as I transfer lots of files between computers.

Comment: What's the error you see when you try to run those commands?  Also, what's the output of `echo %path%` show you from the terminal?    As an aside, running cacls.exe is not the same as running a batch file.

Comment: Error Message: 'cacls.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Run echo %path% - C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\;%Systemroot%\system32;%Systemroot%;%Systemroot%\system32\WEB;C:\Program Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v.10

Comment: So what does `echo %Systemroot%` report?  And am I correct in understanding that you're trying to run the commands in your question from a command prompt?  Not from within a batch file?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for delay in reply Ernie. Mange to resolved problem by changing the command in registry. Apparently, after I install windows resource kit, the command seems to changed to the current rendering any dos command not recognizable ... This is the reason why I am not able to run the batch file. Thx for yr help

Comment: What does this mean?